# rake db:migrate gets error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dbmigrate

I have just recently cloned a sample rails application I am working on onto my macbook and I am trying to run rake db:migrate but I get the following error

```
rake aborted!
/Users/anderskitson/Sites/sample_app/db/migrate/20130207032207_add_password_digest_to_users.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

Here is the rb file

```
raclass AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the first line, first word (raClass). It should be:

```
 Class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
      end
    end
```

Comment: after fixing the type running rake db:migrate still generates the same error. hmmm?

Comment: try:
`rake db:reset
rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Try using "class" instead of "Class"...